# How to add a layer to SelectFeature without losing existing selections?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

I'm using an [OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/SelectFeature-js.html) for selections on multiple layers. However, when I add a layer using setLayer(), my selections on the other layers are lost.

Anyone know how to work around this? I would like to keep my existing selections on other layers when I add a layer to the SelectFeature control.

Here is an example:
**[MY EXAMPLE](http://users8.jabry.com/captdragon/dev/featureSelection.htm)**

**Update:**

I'm aware that this is part of the API. But i'm looking for a work around.

```
/**
 * APIMethod: setLayer
 * Attach a new layer to the control, overriding any existing layers.
 *
 * Parameters:
 * layers - Array of {<OpenLayers.Layer.Vector>} or a single
 *     {<OpenLayers.Layer.Vector>}
 */
setLayer: function(layers) {
    var isActive = this.active;
    this.unselectAll();
    this.deactivate();
    if(this.layers) {
        this.layer.destroy();
        this.layers = null;
    }
    this.initLayer(layers);
    this.handlers.feature.layer = this.layer;
    if (isActive) {
        this.activate();
    }
},
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could modify setLayer method of SelectFeature control:

```
OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature.prototype.setLayer = function(layers) {
    var isActive = this.active;
    //this.unselectAll(); <- what you need
    this.deactivate();
    if(this.layers) {
        this.layer.destroy();
        this.layers = null;
    }
    this.initLayer(layers);
    this.handlers.feature.layer = this.layer;
    if (isActive) {
        this.activate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course i can! Don't know why i didn't think of that. Thanks! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a very useful method but it should be added as addLayer(Layer) and with some small changes to make it handle one layer:

```
addLayer = function(layer) {
  var isActive = this.active;
  var currLayers = this.layers; 
  this.deactivate();
  if(this.layers) {
      this.layer.destroy();
      this.layers = null;
  }
  if ( currLayers != null) {
      currLayers.push(layer);   
      this.initLayer(currLayers);
  } else {
      this.initLayer([layer]);
  }
  this.handlers.feature.layer = this.layer;
  if (isActive) {
      this.activate();
  }
},
```

which i hope will be taken in in this pull request - https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/1287

Also then the user dont have to maintain a list of layers that have been added.